# R - Clustered bar chart with varying widths in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with subgroups and I want to display 2 pieces of data in a bar chart (one using the height of the bar and one using the bar width).

I would call it a clustered bar chart with varying bar widths.

This is what I have so far:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Year = c('2010',rep('2011', 2), rep('2012', 3), rep('2013', 4)),
                 Subyear = c('2010','2010','2011','2010','2011','2012','2010','2011','2012','2013'),
                 Size = c(100, 50, 150, 25, 45, 140, 10, 25, 50, 200),
                 Pct = runif(10, 20, 150) / 100)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = Pct, fill = Subyear, width = Size/500)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

This is the plot I get. It's close, but I want the subyear bars displayed as clustered bars (instead of overlapping).

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *"I want the subyear bars displayed as clustered bars"*? Do you mean a stacked barchart?

Comment: I mean I want them side-by-side. So for year 2011, I want the subyear 2010 and subyear 2011 bars side-by-side, with the subyear 2011 bar wider than the other.

Comment: I see (I think); please take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided I understood you correctly, you can use `position = "dodge2"`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = Pct, fill = Subyear, width = Size/500)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge2")
```

[image]

From the [`ggplot2::position_dodge`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html) reference (bold face mine):

> Dodging preserves the vertical position of an geom while adjusting the horizontal position. **position_dodge2 is a special case of position_dodge for arranging box plots, which can have variable widths**. position_dodge2 also works with bars and rectangles.